# No stereoscopic view with Unity + GoogleVR on iOS

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I built a VR game using Unity, that includes the GoogleVR SDK for Cardboard support.

On Android, it works like a charm: the VR mode is activated with stereoscopic view with the Cardboard distortion.

On iOS, however, it's fine on Unity's emulator but not on device: no stereoscopic view, no gyroscope movement. The GoogleVR SDK seems to have been disabled.
I reproduced this with GoogleVR's sample project.
Following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-ios

**What's expected (screenshot from Android):**

[image: Stereoscopic_Android]

**What's happening (screenshot from iOS):**

[image: Monoscopic_ios]

Versions:

- Unity 5.4.2f2 - GV13 Personal
- Google VR SDK for Unity v1.10
- Xcode 8.2
- iPhone 6 iOS 10.1 and iPhone 7 iOS 10.2.1

What am I doing wrong and what should I check? Thanks!

Comment: Tried again from scratch, using the newest Google VR SDK for Unity (v1.20) and encountered the same problem agin. Any help welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading to Unity 5.5+ solved the issue.